# iPhone- ios localnotification with sliding expiration

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, appcelerator

Can i create a Local notfication in an iphone app with sliding expiration.

My problem statement is that i want to show user a local notification in case the app is terminated by IOS or by an exception.

So to achieve this i am trying to do the following

Create a thread that runs every 5 seconds. This thread first cancels all scheduled notification and then schedules a notification with currenttime +10 seconds.

This way if the app gets killed then the user will be notified within 10 seconds that the app is terminated.

Please advise

Thanks,Amit

Answer (score 0):

Implement the below method...

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Cancel all local notification.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; 

   // Create an future date with 10+ second

    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setSecond:10];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0]; 

    // Scheduled the notification

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    [localNotification setFireDate:fireDate];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"Application Terminated"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
}
```

***UPDATE***

From the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:)

> For apps that do not support background execution or are linked
>   against iOS 3.x or earlier, this method is always called when the user
>   quits the app. For apps that support background execution, this method
>   is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app
>   simply moves to the background in that case. However, **this method may
>   be called in situations where the app is running in the background
>   (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason**.

Comment: Tapas, this function never gets calls if the app is terminated my either an exception or ios killing it. It only gets called when a user kills it. So this is not going to work for me